# Button Background is Transparent When Navigating to Page (UWP)

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a very simple Xamarin Forms application that navigates between two pages.

On the second page (the page being navigated to) the following XAML content exists:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="TEST" />
</StackLayout>
```

When the page has this content, the page appears to render correctly.  However, if I change the XAML to this:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Button Text="TEST" />
</StackLayout>
```

The button background appears to be transparent until I hover over the button.  It appears that any combination of values for the HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions properties causes this effect.

Interestingly, if I set the second page as the root page, the button background is not transparent even when the properties are set.

I am using the Prism framework if that makes any difference.

What am I missing?  Is this behavior correct?

Comment: Can you provide the sample to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT - I don't believe I have ever included a sample on this site (other than *code* such as what I included above).  I do not see a way to attach things.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should anyone stumble upon this question, I submitted an issue on GitHub ([here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4635)). It has been confirmed as a bug.